# php mysqlquery with subquery and group by

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I am trying to fill a table with informations out of a query but i am getting error 500.
What am I doing wrong?

```
for($count = 0; $count < $200; $count++)
    {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT jp.ARTNUM, jp.BEZEICHNUNG, SUM(jp.MENGE), RDATUM
                        FROM journalpos jp, journal j
                        WHERE j.REC_ID=jp.JOURNAL_ID AND ARTNUM IS NOT NULL AND jp.JOURNAL_ID IN
                        (SELECT REC_ID FROM journal WHERE RDATUM BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND NOW() )
                        GROUP BY ARTNUM 
                        LIMIT $count , 30")
    or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['jp.ARTNUM'];
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['jp.BEZEICHNUNG'];
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['SUM(jp.MENGE)'];
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['RDATUM'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

It worked without the SUM function (then i can leave GROUP BY away) and without the subquery !

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: As far as I am aware, 500 internal server error (if that is truly what you meant) wont be thrown by your php script (that would be a php error handled by php not apache etc). what does /var/log/message show? have you just added or edited a htaccess file? (common reason)

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SUM(jp.MENGE) in C:\Programme\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\test18.php on line 48
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SUM(jp.MENGE)

so i guess echo $row['SUM(jp.MENGE)'] is the problem? but how is it called then?

Answer (score 0):

One error I found is in this line

```
for($count = 0; $count < $200; $count++)
```

$200 is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the non-aggregate columns in your select - try:

```
GROUP BY jp.ARTNUM, jp.BEZEICHNUNG, SUM(jp.MENGE), RDATUM
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this item in the select list to have a name:

```
SUM(jp.MENGE)
```

like so:

```
SUM(jp.MENGE) AS SUM_MENGE
```

and then use 'SUM_MENGE' in the array in your PHP like so:

```
 echo $row['SUM_MENGE'];
```

I expect MySQL is generating a column name for it that is not the one you are using. By choosing the column name, you have control over it and know what it is.